# In angular-ui calendar, how can I find index of an event in 'events' array on eventClick?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular-ui

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/

Is there a  way, by which I can find the index of an 'event' inside 'events' array.
Whenever any event is clicked, an alert message says "XYZ event was clicked". Now I need to find the index of that event so that I can use it in splice in order to replace that event by some other event.

Currently, I am using a modal to edit the clicked event. Now, I want to replace that event by a new event using splice. But I need the index of the clicked event to use splice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could search for it once the event is clicked. I know its not very performant but the index of the event is not readily available in terms the Angular context or even the calendar's.

I would also go ahead and replace the event once I find it. No need for the index anymore. Just find the event and replace.

so when the event is clicked.

```
findAndReplaceEventInScopeEvents(event);
```

Comment: Can we directly pass event object and then use it for modification?

Comment: not sure what you mean... The event is passed into the eventClick function. That is where you place this logic.

Comment: I meant can we pass 'event' object to another function for modification?

Comment: well it will not be the same event as the one on the scope. This is why you need to find it first and then edit the event on the scope, so the calendar will pick up your edits and updated itself.

Comment: Actually, I want to edit the same event. Thats why I needed index to find the event.
Anyway, I found a workaround. Thanks for writing!